# SQL Server max connection settings

Tags: sql-server-2005, iis-6

On a machine that is running IIS 6.0 and SQL Server 2005, where are the different locations that can limit the max number of database connections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "number of connections" you mean the size of the connection pool, then this applies:

> A connection pool is created for each
>   unique connection string. When a pool
>   is created, multiple connection
>   objects are created and added to the
>   pool so that the minimum pool size
>   requirement is satisfied. Connections
>   are added to the pool as needed, up to
>   the maximum pool size specified (100
>   is the default). Connections are
>   released back into the pool when they
>   are closed or disposed.
>
> When a SqlConnection object is
>   requested, it is obtained from the
>   pool if a usable connection is
>   available. To be usable, a connection
>   must be unused, have a matching
>   transaction context or be unassociated
>   with any transaction context, and have
>   a valid link to the server.
>
> The connection pooler satisfies
>   requests for connections by
>   reallocating connections as they are
>   released back into the pool. If the
>   maximum pool size has been reached and
>   no usable connection is available, the
>   request is queued. The pooler then
>   tries to reclaim any connections until
>   the time-out is reached (the default
>   is 15 seconds). If the pooler cannot
>   satisfy the request before the
>   connection times out, an exception is
>   thrown.

Source: [SQL Server Connection Pooling (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx)

The default size of connection pools is 100. You can change that size in in the connectionstring itself, but you should have a good reason to do that. In most cases where you run out of connections, they are leaking (=not properly closed) in the application.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the server properties in Management studio, on the connections page, there is a Maximum number of concurrent connections setting.

Right click on the server in object explorer and select properties.
Click Connections in the left-hand pane.

Answer (score 0):

Properties on the SQL server instance.  Right-click on the instance in Mgmt Studio and get properties the click on Connections.  Are you having a specific problem with connections?